# Complicated multiple integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to evaluate the integrals $D_1$ and $D_2$ defined below.

```
ax[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := (
 2*ϵ*Δ)/(ϵ^2 + Δ^2)* 
  Sin[(Δ*η)/2]^2;

ay[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := Δ/
 Sqrt[ϵ^2 + Δ^2]* 
  Sin[Δ*η];

az[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := 
 1 - (2*Δ^2)/(ϵ^2 + Δ^2)* 
  Sin[(Δ*η)/2]^2;

r1[ϵ_, Δ_, η_, θ_, ϕ_] :=  \
 -ax[ϵ, Δ, η]*Cos[ϕ]*Cos[θ] - 
   a_y[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[ϕ]*
    Cos[θ] + 
     a_z[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[θ];

 r2[ϵ_, Δ_, η_, θ_, ϕ_] := 
  ay[ϵ, Δ, η]*Cos[ϕ] - 
   ax[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[ϕ];

(*We choose θ = π/3 and ϕ = 0*)

 D1[ϵ_, Δ_, ω_, τ_]   =  
  Integrate[
   Cos[ω*
    t']*(r1[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/3 , 0]*
     r1[ϵ, Δ, t, π/3 , 0] + 
      r2[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/3 , 0]*
       r2[ϵ, Δ, t, π/3 , 0]), {u, 0, t}, {t, 
       0, τ}]

D2[ϵ_, Δ_, ω_, τ_]   =  
 Integrate[
  Sin[ω*
   t']*(r1[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/3 , 0]*
    r1[ϵ, Δ, t, π/3 , 0] - 
     r2[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/3 , 0]*
      r2[ϵ, Δ, t, π/3 , 0]), {u, 0, t}, {t, 
       0, τ}]
```

When I execute the code, I get nothing. No output and no errors! What is wrong with the code?

You can find more details on the expressions at: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06561v1.pdf. Page 6, left column.

P.S: I have no idea how to properly paste the code. I have been trying to copy (and paste) the code as "plain/input text" but to no avail. Please let me know how properly post my code.

---

Udpate: After the suggested edits (reflected in the code above), I get the following output:

[image]

I suspect the integrals haven't been evaluated since the integral signs are still with the expression. When I exclude the expressions involing `r1` etc, leaving behind only the `Sin` and `Cos` terms in the respective integrals, *Mathematica* evaluates the double integral. Issues?

The paper does evaluate the integrals. Shouldn't *Mathematica* be able to reproduce the results? The results are:

[image]

Comment: Do you realise that you cannot have "_" in variable names?

Comment: @mikado Edited. I can define the functions properly now. No error uptil the definition of `r2`. `D1` and `D2` still don't evalauate -- I still get the last 2 errors posted above.

Comment: @mikado Updated the post with the amended code/problem.

Comment: They're just definitions, aren't they?  You not supposed to get output with `SetDelayed` (`:=`).

Comment: [This meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) has tips on copying code to the site.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to run the integrations and save the resulting expressions in functions `D1` and `D2.` What should be the correct format?

Comment: Try `=` instead of `:=` for those two.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Check the edit.

Comment: Do you realize that `t'` is short for `Derivative[1][t]`, i.e., the first derivative of the symbol `t`, treated as a function of one variable?  Second, you want `Sin[x]^2` not `Sin^2[x]`. Third, possibly, after the syntax errors are fixed, the integral still cannot be evaluated in terms of standard functions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Made the changes (to the `Sin` functions and changing `t'` to `u`). I still get the same error. See the error. Actually, the paper derives the expression for `D1` and `D2`. Check the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a syntax error in the beginning.

```
a_z -> az
a_y -> ay
```

Below is your code with modified `a_z, a_y` replaced with `az, ay` respectively.

```
ax[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := (2*ϵ*Δ)/(ϵ^2 + Δ^2)*Sin[(Δ*η)/2]^2

ay[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := Δ Sqrt[ϵ^2 + Δ^2]*Sin[Δ*η]

az[ϵ_, Δ_, η_] := 1 - (2*Δ^2)/(ϵ^2 + Δ^2)*Sin[(Δ*η)/2]^2

r1[ϵ_, Δ_, η_, θ_, ϕ_] := -ax[ϵ, Δ, η]*Cos[ϕ]*Cos[θ] - 
  ay[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[ϕ]*Cos[θ] + az[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[θ]

r2[ϵ_, Δ_, η_, θ_, ϕ_] := ay[ϵ, Δ, η]*Cos[ϕ] - ax[ϵ, Δ, η]*Sin[ϕ]
```

Now, in the paper they use the two variables `t` and `t'`. You are using `t` and `u`. This is good. As was mentioned in a comment `t'` is the derivative and you don't want to use that.

So let's replace `t'` in the integration code with `u`. Also in the paper they used `π/2` so I will do that as well.

I also think you have the integration order swapped. You had the `u` variable followed by the `t` variable. When doing multiple integrals the outside integration variable should be in the first list. Check out the traditional form

```
HoldForm[Integrate[Cos[ω*u]*
    (r1[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r1[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0] +
      r2[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r2[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0]),
   {t, 0, τ}, {u, 0, t}]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's see if we can get an analytical result

```
d1Int = Integrate[Cos[ω*u]*(
    r1[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r1[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0] + 
     r2[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r2[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0]
    ),
  {t, 0, τ}, {u, 0, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We will define D1 using this result

```
D1[ϵ_, Δ_, ω_, τ_] := d1Int
```

And for `D2`

```
d2Int = Integrate[Sin[ω*u]*(
    r1[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r1[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0] - 
     r2[ϵ, Δ, t - u, π/2, 0]*r2[ϵ, Δ, t, π/2, 0]
    ),
  {u, 0, t}, {t, 0, τ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
D2[ϵ_, Δ_, ω_, τ_] := d2Int
```

Hope this helps. I leave it to you to check whether it matches the result from the paper.